# Overwriting network interfaces file using a Bash setup script

Tags: linux, bash

I am kind of in a Dilemma here, I have a decent sized [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/ComNets-Bremen/TWIN) and I want to create a `setup.sh` or a `bootstrap.sh` which once run as `root` would download some necessary **Python pip modules** and **apt repositories** on the triggered machines.

> The Repository is aimed at Raspberry Pis running on **Raspbian Jessie 8.0**. Pis need to be setup as AdHoc Network Nodes. However, the script I wish to write can be used on any **Debian** Distribution based Laptop too.

I want this `setup.sh`/`bootstrap.sh` file to also create a *backup* of the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and overwrite the original one by configuring the interfaces as follows:

```
## Desired Interfaces file
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

## Ethernet LAN
iface eth0 inet dhcp

## WLAN AdHoc
auto wlan0
allow hot-plug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet6 auto ## IPv6
```

I want to write the complete above mentioned data  into the `setup.sh` but  I think that is not a standard practice!

Should I create a `interfaces.txt` file and have it contain the above mentioned details and then use `>` or `>>` in my `setup.sh`?

#### Example

something like

```
# in the setup.sh file
cat interfaces.txt > /etc/network/interfaces

cat adhoc.txt > /etc/rc.local
```

where, `adhoc.txt` contains

```
adhocNet(){
    ifconfig wlan0 down
    iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc essid my-ESSID channel 1 txpower 3dBm
    ifconfig wlan0 up
}
adhocNet()
exit 0
```

I want to create this bash script which can *make things for end user much Easier!* (Just a thought here!)

### Question

Does this imply I have to create a `.txt` file for all setups that I wish to configure on my GNU/Linux machine or is there a middle ground to it?

How do big repositories create such bash scripts so that the end user finds it easy initially to use.

Comment: Could you edit and expand your question to describe your goal in more detail?  Why do you want to install pip modules, apt repositories, and edit the interfaces, and do all of that in one script?

Comment: @StandardEyre Hello, I have updated the question as detailed as I can.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep everything in one file you will have to have the files you want to modify within your script. To make your script better readable you can use something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7875598/760942

One more thing you should consider: eth0 is very common, but not necessary the actual name of the network interface. Especially since [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) seem to become more and more common.

Comment: Hi, yes I realize `eth0` is very common, however I have overwritten the interface names on most of the Pis and Laptops for simplicity of understanding. Thanks